# type a = {X:int; Y:int} vs type a = |X of int |Y of int

Tags: math, f#, set

I'm really more interested in the theoretical-set answer. So maybe I should ask int * int vs int + int. I interpret int * int as a tuple with cardinal of int squared as the number of combinations.

Comment: I would think the number of possible values for int * int would be nCr(|int|, 2). Sorry for commenting here. I cannot comment on answers. But I don't see the difference between the possible values of int * int and int + int.

Comment: As to the difference between `A*B` and `A+B`, the possible values of the first type are `(a_i,b_j)` while the values for the second are `X a_i` or `Y b_j`.  Does that help?

Comment: I think I answered my question. When you work with |X of int |Y of int after declaration you will be working with only one subset at a time (X or Y). With a product type you are working with both variables. I can't answer my own question but I think that's my answer.

Comment: Yes that does help. I think we are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find out more about the theory, you can search for information about *product types* (tuples are a basic case, records are *labeled* products) and *sum types* (the `Choice<..>` type in F# is a basic case, discriminated unions are *labeled* sum types).

The set-theoretical interpretation is that product types correspond to product of sets and sum types correspond to a union (more precisely to a [disjoint union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union) - because they are labeled).

So, assuming that `[| T |]` is a set representing values of a type `T`:

> [| T<sub>1</sub> * T<sub>2</sub> |] = { (v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>) | v<sub>1</sub> ∈ [| T<sub>1</sub> |], v<sub>2</sub> ∈ [| T<sub>2</sub> |] }
>   [| T<sub>1</sub> + T<sub>2</sub> |] = { (1, v) | v ∈ [| T<sub>1</sub> |] } ∪ { (2, v) | v ∈ [| T<sub>2</sub> |] }

A simpler version of the `+` operation would be just union, but that only makes sense when the two types have distinct values (and so you can distinguish between without the labels):

> [| T<sub>1</sub> + T<sub>2</sub> |] = [| T<sub>1</sub> |] ∪ [| T<sub>2</sub> |]

This is actually quite fun, because you can find out that many of the standard algebraic laws will work for types too. For example, distributivity says that: `(a + b) * c = (a * c) + (b * c)`. This works for types too and it means that the following two are equivalent:

```
type AorB = A of int | B of string            // int + string
type AorBandC = AorB * float                  // (int + string) * float

type AandC = int * float                      // int * float
type BandC = string * float                   // string * float
type AandCorBandC = AC of AandC | BC of BandC // (int * float) + (string * float)
```

You can write a pair of functions that will map between the values of `AorBandC` and `AandCorBandC`. In fact, you can go even wilder and even differentiate types. This is a bit crazy, but you asked for a theory: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/publ/jpartial.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, record types are just like tuple types, except that their elements have names.  As the F#/ML syntax for tuples types suggests, a tuple of type `A * B * C * ...` has |A| * |B| * |C| * ... possible values.  Likewise, you are also right that a discriminated union `| N1 of A | N2 of B | ...` has |A| + |B| + ... possible values.  You didn't mention it, but function types correspond to exponentiation: `A -> B` has |B|<sup>|A|</sup> inhabitants.